# pass user information by routes

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-blade, middleware

I have a blade file has the user information

```
{{$user -> name}}
{{$user -> age}}
{{$user -> gender}}
```

also I have a form to add the permissions for this user

```
{!! Form::open(['method' => 'post'])!!}
<div>
<label >
<input type="checkbox" value="1"> Setting
</label>
<label >
<input type="checkbox "value="1"> Users
</label>
<label>
<input type="checkbox"  value="1"> Images
</label>
</div>
<br>
{!! Form::submit('Save')!!}
{!! Form::close()!!}
```

and I send the id of the user by routes like this

```
Route::post('roles/{$user-> name}','control@save_roles');
```

to this function to save it

```
   public function save_roles(Request $request,$id)
{
    $role = new Role;
    $role -> user_id =  $user -> name;
    if($request ->has('setting')){$role ->setting = 1;}
    if($request ->has('users')){$role ->users = 1;}
    if($request ->has('images')){$role ->images = 1;}
    $role -> save();
    return redirct('users');
}
```

but not work

Comment: What does "not work" mean exactly?

Comment: I think that is a problem when send user_id from blade to controller by route

Answer (score 1):

I think your route should be

```
Route::post('roles/{$userId}','control@save_roles');
```

and your controller function

```
public function save_roles(Request $request, $userId)
{
    $role = new Role;
    $role->user_id =  $userId;
.
.
.
}
```

Comment: $userId also not posted

Answer (score 0):

You have done something wrong here maybe:

```
 public function save_roles(Request $request,$id)
{
    $role = new Role;
    $role->user_id =  $request->name;
    if($request->has('setting')){$role->setting = 1;}
    if($request->has('users')){$role->users = 1;}
    if($request->has('images')){$role->images = 1;}
    $role->save();
    return redirct('users');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, you have several issues that need to be fixed.

First, let's fix your route:

```
Route::post('roles/{username}','control@save_roles');
```

Then your form, needs an action to POST information to:

```
{!! Form::open(['method' => 'post','action'=>['control@save_roles',$user->name]])!!}
<div>
<label >
<input type="checkbox" value="1"> Setting
</label>
<label >
<input type="checkbox "value="1"> Users
</label>
<label>
<input type="checkbox"  value="1"> Images
</label>
</div>
<br>
{!! Form::submit('Save')!!}
{!! Form::close()!!}
```

Finally, in your Controller action:

```
public function save_roles(Request $request,$username)
{
    $role = new Role;
    $role -> user_id =  $username;
    if($request ->has('setting')){$role ->setting = 1;}
    if($request ->has('users')){$role ->users = 1;}
    if($request ->has('images')){$role ->images = 1;}
    $role -> save();
    return redirect('users');
}
```